# Отправка писем на почту не указывая отправителя

Tags: c#, email, smtp, веб-служба

Подскажите пожалуйста. Пишу Windows службу на C#, как мне отправлять данные на почту, знаю типичный метод отправки: SmtpClient  и MailAddress. Мне не нравится, что надо вводить адрес отправителя, можно ли это как то обойти? Либо посоветуйте, как лучше сделать.

Comment: Введите фейковый адрес отправителя, почему это проблема? Если SMTP сервер позволяет слать через себя любые письма, то отправка будет выполнена. Если вы используете нормальный SMTP сервер в соответствии со всеми стандартами безопасности, то без разницы, какой вы будете использовать клиент, SMTP сервер не будет отправлять вашу почту.

Comment: @aepot `Введите фейковый адрес отправителя` Многие почтовые сервисы требуют указывания правильного обратного адреса привязанного к аккаунту.

Comment: @ГеннадийП а я о чем выше написал? Об этом же самом.

Comment: Подобные методы без отправителя характерны для спамеров. Вы спамер или хотите быть им? Если не хотите -- то вводите нормальный, валидный адрес отправителя, потому что современные методы проверки антиспам-систем просто будут ваши письма блокировать (и в лучшем случае попадут в папку "спам", а на некоторых системах с очень строгими политиками типа как на mail.ru вообще нигде не будет такое письмо светиться) Альтернативно можете поднять собственный smtp-сервер и познайте всю глубину кроличьей норы с вопросами антиспама. Как надоест - просто подставляйте валидного отправителя.